# Resume my App after Back pressed from google map Application

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-fragments, android-intent

I am facing this issue when i open the google map application by using Intent and start activity. when i press back then my application is not resumed.
here is the code

I tried checking OnDestroy method in activity , but its not triggered.

```
String uri ="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+saddr.latitude+","+saddr.longitude+"&daddr="+daddr.latitude+","+daddr.longitude;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    startActivity(intent);
```

when i press back from google map application, it should resume back the application. your suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

step 1: click on Start navigation. ( this is Fragment inside the mainActivity) and it google map application is launched from this Fragment.
[Start Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdA9e.png)

Step-2: Google map application is launched.

[Google Map Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49QZA.png)

Step-3: it goes back to the login Activity.

Comment: what does it do now instead of returning to your app?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko it goes back to the first activity , which is Login activity.

Comment: share all code here

Comment: looks like your app is killed in process of google maps usage.

Answer (score 0):

If it kills your app, just create an activity with fullscreen webview and pass the url to it, so the user will never leave your app

Comment: means , instead of launching google map application. i should open the map in webView  in the application ?

Comment: Yes exactly that is the best solution I think

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```